# AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got the following error, when I run the program. I attached my error and program as follows. What's wrong with my program?

```
import random
index=random.randint(0,len(X_test)-1)
samples = X_test[index].ravel()
print("Audio:",classes[np.argmax(y_test[index])])
ipd.Audio(samples, rate=16000)
```

Any idea what has gone wrong?

Comment: is `X_test` a numpy array?

Comment: Please correct the formatting and add the code for `X_test`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `numpy` behavior for `EagerTensor` objects. Use the following snippet:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
```

Answer (score 0):

ravel() is a [numpy function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and can only operate on numpy objects. You can solve this problem by converting X_test into numpy data type e.g. if X_test is tensor then X_test.numpy() will return you numpy object.